# jquery API request error/ won't show giphy's

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code and why my API/AJAX call will not show the images that I'm calling. It appears when I console.log(results) the 10 images are called but they will not show. Here is my jquery code..
//when window loads ... function will happen
    window.onload = function(){

```
var musiciansList = [];
var inputBox = $('#submitButton')

//whatever musician the user submits will appear
$('#submitButton').on('click', function(){
    var input=$('#submitButton');
    var userInput=inputBox.val();
    musiciansList.push(userInput);
    renderButtons();
});

function renderButtons() {
        var button = $('<button>');
        button.text(musiciansList[musiciansList.length-1]);
        button.addClass('band')
        $('.container').append(button);

};

//When I click this button a function will happen
$(document).on('click', '.band', function() {

//variable queryUrl for giphy
var queryUrl = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=music&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=10";

    //requesting information giphy
    $.ajax({
        url: queryUrl,
        method: 'GET'
    })//recieving information from giphy
    .done(function(response) {      
        //returns the response from the website
        var results = response.data;
        var imageUrl = response.data.image_original_url; 
        var musicians = $('<img>');         
        console.log(queryUrl)

        //takes var musicians and adds attr src and imageUrl
        musicians.attr('src', imageUrl);
        musicians.attr('alt', 'musician');
        $("#images").push(imageUrl)

        //prepend puts the images in the beginning
        $("#images").prepend(imageUrl);
        $('<img>').val();
        console.log(results)
        console.log(imageUrl)   


        //empty gifs button
        $('#clearButton').click(function(event){
            $(musicians).remove()

        });
    });
});
```

};

Comment: `response.data` does not appear to have a property `image_original_url`?

Comment: You are missing to prepend/append/add musicians to $("#images") /any DOM element

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you've got a couple of errors.

First one looks like your usage of the giphy API. If you go to http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=music&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=10 in your browser, you can see how the data is coming back. The data is returned as an array of GIF objects that each have an "images" property that has an assortment of images you can choose from. Instead of accessing the images like

```
var imageUrl = response.data.image_original_url;
```

you need to loop through the response.data array and grab an image, as in the following example

```
var imageUrl = response.data[i].images.fixed_height.url;
```

Your other issue is when appending the image element you created to the DOM. You are appending the imageUrl variable (which is just the value of the image URL), instead of the img element you created which is stored in the musicians variable (this will also have to be a part of your loop). In addition, the following:

```
$("#images").push(imageUrl)

//prepend puts the images in the beginning
$("#images").prepend(imageUrl);
$('<img>').val();
```

can all be refactored to the single line

```
$("#images").prepend(musicians);
```

Your end result should look something like:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
        var imageUrl = response.data[i].images.fixed_height.url; 
        var musicians = $('<img>');         

        //takes var musicians and adds attr src and imageUrl
        musicians.attr('src', imageUrl);
        musicians.attr('alt', 'musician');

        //prepend puts the images in the beginning
        $("#images").prepend(musicians);
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I read what you said and than just copied over the for loop and yet there are still no images. I'm still not sure what i am doing wrong. could it have something to do with my HTML? I feel like I'm missing a .val() somewhere?

Comment: <h1>Put in your favorites bands!</h1>
 <label for="music-input">Search for any band: </label>
 <input type="text" name="username" id='submitBox'>
 <button id='submitButton'>Submit</button>
 <button id='clearButton'>Push to Clear</button><br/>
<div class='container'>
  <button class="band">Sublime</button>
  <button class="band">Green Day</button>
  <button class="band">Rolling Stones</button>
  <button class="band">Blink-182</button>
  <button class="band">Pink Floyd</button>   
</div>
<div class="gifsAppearHere"> </div>

Comment: Yea it looks like you have a problem with your HTML. I don't see an element with the id "images" anywhere. When you are using

    $('#images')

What you are saying is "go to my html, and find the element that has the id 'images'"

for instance

    <div id="images"></div>

In your case, that is the element to which you are trying to append all your gifs.

From what I can tell from what you are doing, you don't need any .val() anywhere

Comment: It wouldn't let me put in my whole HTML nor is that how it is organized. What was wrong with my HTML? Is there a way to show my HTML?

Comment: I am still new to web development if you haven't noticed too so I'm still learning

Comment: Check out my comment above, I re-edited it. I suspect you are missing an element with the id "images"

Comment: Cool! Happy to help